# Is is a good idea to wrap class instances in a struct?

Tags: c#, struct, reference

I have a method that accepts a few arguments:

```cs
public Something GetMeSomething(Class1 class1, Class2 class2, Class3 class3, bool someOption);
```

I don't like the fact that it accepts so many arguments, with some `bool` at the end, which also doesn't look great. Int the context of this method these arguments are related to each other, and they could be a part of a single object.

However, I do not want to create a new class like this:

```cs
record SomeArguments(
  Class1 Class1,
  Class2 Class2,
  Class3 Class3,
  bool SomeOption
);
```

because it incurs allocations.

However, I thought about making it a struct:

```cs
record struct SomeArguments(
  Class1 Class1,
  Class2 Class2,
  Class3 Class3,
  bool SomeOption
);
```

I know that it's not advised to use struct when the content of it is bigger than 16 bytes. I assume that this struct will be bigger than that, it would probably store pointers to instances of the classes inside.

What would you do?

Comment: Firstly, that structure would not be bigger than 16 bytes. The size of the classes is irrelevant because the structure only contains references to the instances. It has fields that would be 4 bytes each.

Comment: The method should only care about itself, not the context(s) in which it might be used. If those three class instances will always be associated in the same way then you'd already have a type that bound them together and you could use that. As that's not the case, just stick with the individual instances. There's nothing wrong with the first declaration you posted.

Comment: I seem to remember style guides indicating that up to five arguments is ok and after that to use a class to contain them the way you have with the SomeArguments in your text. I wouldn't worry about the extra allocations in initializing it as I would place readability above this level of optimization. You probably aren't working on something that needs this level of optimization when you're using C#?

Comment: Well, the thing I don't like is a boolean argument, which usually suggests that the method does too many things. In this case it's a simple flag that is passed on to message bus, so it makes sense to keep it as an argument. In the end, it's a matter of taste. The recommendation of up to 5 arguments is also just someone's opinion - why not 4? Why not 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> not advised to use struct when the content of it is bigger than 16 bytes

This rule really needs a disclaimer. You should certainly try to keep structs small, but there is no real limit. It really depends on how it is used.

In your specific example you are copying the same amount of data if you call `GetMeSomething` with separate parameters, or with all parameters in a struct. So I would not expect a significant difference.

You can often also avoid the copy overhead by passing structs with the [in parameter modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier).

> I assume that this struct will be bigger than that

Yes, if running in 64 bit mode each reference will use 8 bytes, so probably 52 bytes. Use [Marshal.SizeOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof?view=net-7.0) to check. Keep in mind that the System.Numerics.Matrix4x4 is 64 bytes, so such a size is not necessarily a concern.

If you are concerned about allocations or performance, the most important part is to *measure*. Run a profiler and see if you can see any difference. Chances are that there is an irrelevant or immeasurable difference. Most code run rarely enough that performance concerns are nearly irrelevant. It is better to profile the code and spend the effort at optimizing the places that actually matter.

As for if it is a good idea to wrap parameters in a struct, it really comes down to readability. If you think it makes the code clearer and more readable, go for it.